# Failure reading data out of document using Firestore

Tags: javascript, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using Ionic 3 with Firestore and AngulareFire2/5 and have some issue getting datas out of my document.

```
async getLocalisation() {
  const localisation = await this.afs.doc(`/localisation/France/`)
    .ref
    .get()
    .then(data => console.log(data.data));
}
```

The console is displaying the actual data prototype :

```
DocumentSnapshot.prototype.data = function () {
    validateExactNumberOfArgs('DocumentSnapshot.data', arguments, 0);
    if (!this._document) {
        throw new FirestoreError(Code.NOT_FOUND, "This document doesn't exist. Check doc.exists to make sure " +
            'the document exists before calling doc.data().');
    }
    return this.convertObject(this._document.data);
};
```

How can I get my datas without using valueChanges() as my datas won't be updated at all?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've managed to solved my issue, I guess I was to tired on this one.
`data` is a method and not a property, I just needed to execute the method.

```
async getLocalisation() {
  const ref = await this.afs.doc(`/localisation/France/`).ref;
  const result = await ref.get();
  console.log(result.data());
}
```